# Probability on Infinite Sets.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Q.1 What is the probability of ***randomly*** selecting an even number from the set of natural numbers.
Q.2 What is the probability of ***randomly*** selecting a real number from the interval $[0,1]$, such that the sum of its digits is even?

I am aware that a uniform non zero probability distribution over the any countably infinite set is impossible (if the probability assigned to every number is non zero, then the total probability would sum to more than 1). I expect a uniform distribution is impossible on uncountably infinite sets as well.

I picked the two questions, because my intuition is that the probability of both events should be $\frac{1}{2}$.

For the purpose of this question please assume a technical meaning of random selection.

ETA: I removed the non-zero constraint on the digits of the numbers. This is so that the answer to question 2 intuitively feels like $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I guess the second one might not be 1/2, since zero doesn't matter, so the odd number is 1,3,5,7,9, while even is only 2,4,6,8. then we get the appearance ratio of 5:4, so maybe the answer is 4/9?

Comment: Is the digit sum of $\frac{1}{3}$ even or odd?

Comment: If the sum is even or odd only when it is finite, then only at most $\mathbb{Q}$ have a finite number of non-zero digits, hence the answer is $0$

Comment: @novavita, I corrected that.

Comment: @demigod, I don't know. It makes me suspect the answer is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Re **the 1st question**, there is a [more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206723/probability-that-an-integer-is-divisible-by-a-prime-p)

> What is the probability of a randomly selected integer to be divisible
>   by $m \in \mathbb{N}, m \ne 0$?

The trick is to look at the remainders (as an example see [this problem](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qThxpwa9WoYC&lpg=PA56&ots=Xl5LjHgviN&dq=probability%20of%20an%20integer%20divisible%20by%20n%20remainder&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=remainder&f=false)). According to [Euclid's division theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem), $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \exists q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$: 
$$n=m\cdot q+r, 0\leq r<m$$ 
Looking at the remainders, $r\in \{0, ..., m-1\}$ (effectively, the set $\mathbb{Z}$ [is partitioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)), only $1$ of $m$ cases indicates a divisibility, thus the answer is $P=\frac{1}{m}$. 
Back to the question

> What is the probability of randomly selecting an even number from the
>   set of natural numbers.

$$P(\text{... randomly selecting an even ...})=P(\text{... divisible by 2 ...})=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I'm not sure, if $P$ defined that way is probability. What subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are measurable? For example, what is $P(\{2^n:n\in \mathbb{N}\})$, or $P(\{2^k*n:n\in \mathbb{N}\})$, where $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed?

Comment: @Przemek 1st question is related to discrete probabilities ... besides, it's a well known problem, nothing I invented.

Comment: How do you select  randomly select a number from $\mathbb{N}$? what is the probability distribution? It is well known that this does not exist.

Comment: @miracle173 for example the very 1st link ... did you see it before down-voting?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0 \le r \lt q$?

Comment: It should be $m$, since division theorem is applied to $n$ and $m$, $q$ is the quotient.

Comment: Yes I did. And it states that the concept of probability cannot be used but you have to define the concept of natural density or something similar.

Comment: Yep, which works as a definition of discrete probability ... $\Omega =\{\omega_0,\omega_2,...,\omega_{m-1}\}, \omega_i=\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \equiv i \pmod{m}\}, i=0..m-1$. $P(\omega_i)$ as a function is the natural density and satisfies $P(\omega_i)\geq 0$ and $\sum\limits_{\omega_i \in \Omega}P(\omega_i)=1$

Comment: And yes, I agree it looks like cheating reducing the problem to a partition and applying discrete probabilities (which, by definition, is a function satisfying the rules I mentioned in the previous comment) on partitions ... but it's equivalent, although please don't ask me to prove it's equivalent ;) ... maybe as a separate question.